# error in codeigniter custom where clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm referring the codeigniter user guide to write a custom where clause. 
as per the guide it says for custom where clauses write like this.

```
 $where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";
 $this->db->where($where);
```

but when i use in my model browser is throwing an error.

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'user_name='Joe'' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`Management`) WHERE `user_name='Joe'` AND password='boss' OR password='active'

Filename: /var/www/models/hr_login_model.php

Line Number: 28
```

this is just a testing query. my actual query is dynamic one and it is also giving this error.

```
$where = "user_name='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' AND Department='".$dep_br."' OR Br_no='".$dep_br."'";
```

why it always taking the column name and the value, both as a column name?

Comment: Not a solution, but why not avoiding this unsafe method (you need to manually escape the values) and use a safer, easier one?

Comment: @DamienPirsy - actually I don't know this is a unsafe method. if you can tell me a better way to this i will be thank full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following

```
$where = "user_name='$username' AND password='$password' AND (Department='$dep_br' OR Br_no='$dep_br')";
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: how does CodeIgniter tell out how you composed the string? Does it bypass the PHP parser?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - I tried this. but it needs to put spaces before and after the = sign this to be work. thank you

Comment: I marked this as the best answer for me. because without () the query is giving me unwanted rows. but with () it works as i want. 
but spaces should be there as  Trimantra Software Solution talled. 

@Trimantra Software Solution

Answer (score 3):

User space befor and after = like shown below.

```
$where = "name = 'Joe' AND status = 'boss' OR status = 'active'"; 
$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: That's irrelevant, spaces aren't an issue (they're not even in the doc example)

Comment: yes there is no spaces in the example. but i'll try this also.

Comment: @ Damien Pirsy - They are not documented but if you take a look in to DB_active_rec.php file on line no 430 there is condition which checks operator with ' = '. which mean there should be a space before and after = operator

Comment: @ Yasitha- Do let me know if this solution was helpful to you.

Comment: I must admit I'm stumped! didn't check CI's actual code but this should be pointed out as a bug on their docs (if someone is still taking care of that). Congrats man

Comment: Well To be honest even I didn't checked the code till I faced this issue sometimes back. I struggled a lot and decided to check the core files and then I found it. :)

Comment: some time reading every thing is effective ,
Trimantra Software solution ,thanks it help me

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";
$this->db->where($where, NULL, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way it is much more better and secure

```
$this->db->where("name","joe");
$this->db->where("status =","boss");
$this->db->or_where("status","active");
```