# Codeigniter where clause is not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter I've a function in model with this code

```
    $this->db->select("id, username, password");
    $this->db->from(TABLE_USERS);
    $where = "username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' AND status='1'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $login = $this->db->get();
    echo '<pre>';print_r($login);echo '</pre>';die('Call');
```

And it is giving this error

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'username='admin'' in 'where clause'

SELECT `id`, `username`, `password` FROM (`users`) WHERE `username='admin'` AND password='7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b' AND status='1' LIMIT 1

Filename: C:\wamp\www\customadmin\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

after where clause this should be like this

```
WHERE `username`='admin' AND `password`='7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b'
```

instead of this

```
WHERE `username='admin'` AND password='7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b'
```

I've searched every where like [Active Record Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) and also at stackoverflow [CodeIgniter WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975987/codeigniter-how-to-use-where-clause-and-or-clause) and other forums but didn't find solution related with my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than post a blurry screenshot, couldn't you simply add the error message text to your question?

Comment: Yes I can do it wait...

Comment: You can use a third parameter to `where()` to prevent CI from protecting the table names with backtick, so `$this->db->where($where,NULL,FALSE);` should fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Like this:

```
$where = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'status' => '1');

$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: Is that a question or a sentence? `$this->db->where()` accepts an array of `table=>value` pairs. There's no why, that's how it works

Comment: @Prodikl it accepts a custom string too, the issue in the OP is with the backticks, using `$this->db->where($where,NULL,FALSE);` should fix it

Comment: Ah, derp. In that case it's the backticks, yup. I posted an answer, too.

Comment: how to get proxy ip address using codeigniter??? I know with PHP I've to use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] but in codeigniter what I've to do to grab the proxy ip address???

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** 
You can make a condition string and pass it to where function. but Make sure to add space before and after **Equals to "="**

same thing mentioned on similar thread here [error in codeigniter custom where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836099/error-in-codeigniter-custom-where-clause/20836134#20836134)

```
 $where = "username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' AND status = '1'";
 $this->db->where($where);
```

**Option 2:**

Write code like below.

```
$where = array('username' => $username, 
               'password' => $password, 
               'status'   => '1');
$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: how to get proxy ip address using codeigniter??? I know with PHP I've to use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] but in codeigniter what I've to do to grab the proxy ip address???

Comment: I would suggest you to create another question for this. Or look for similar threads on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

try below code...

```
  function get_user(){
    $this->db->select('id, username, password');
            $where = "username=$username AND password=$password AND status='1'";
    $this->db->where($where);
            $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get('YOUR TABLE NAME');
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this code.

```
    $this->db->select("id, username, password");
    $this->db->from(TABLE_USERS);
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $this->db->where('status', 1);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $login = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column names are wrong, look at this error:

```
SELECT `id`, `username`, `password` 
FROM (`users`) 
WHERE `username='admin'` 
AND password='7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b' 
AND status='1' 
LIMIT 1
```

Line 3. It's looking for a column named

```
`username='admin'`
```

Where it should be

```
`username`='admin' // the tick marks (`) should wrap the column name
```

Try this:

```
$where = "`username`='$username' AND `password`='$password' AND `status`=1";
$this->db->where($where);
```

But honestly the best way is to use an array, or else you risk confusion:

Like this:

```
$this->db->where(array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'status' => 1
));
```

That will escape your variables for you, too, which is safer.

Comment: how to get proxy ip address using codeigniter??? I know with PHP I've to use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] but in codeigniter what I've to do to grab the proxy ip address???

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
$where = "username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' AND status='1'";
```

to

```
$where = "username ='"~~~~~
```

keep a blank between "first column name" with "operator"

in codeigniter v1.0

Answer (score -2):

Its better to use SHA(`$password`) or MD5() value instead Checking with the Hash value directly 
This code might work..!!
and for the query you can make this replacement 
username=`admin` AND password=`7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b` AND status='1' LIMIT 1

Comment: What is the relation of `md5` and `SHA` to do with this question?

Comment: The error mentions an incorrect column name; it's not a problem with hashes

Comment: how to get proxy ip address using codeigniter??? I know with PHP I've to use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] but in codeigniter what I've to do to grab the proxy ip address???